# In Thunderbird mail takes too slow to send or gets an SMTP error message

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird in Ubuntu 16.04, .

When I send mail in Thunderbird, normally it shows in the popup 'connecting', 'connected', 'delivering mail' then the pop up exits. But usually 'delivering mail' stays there for a very long time, around 15 to 20 minutes, or it shows an error:

> sending of the mail failed. The message could not be sent because of the connection to outgoing server (SMTP). mail.xxxxx.com timed out. try again.

I tried to change the pop3 and SMTP ports (POP  port 110 , SSL/TLS encrypted POP port 995 . SMTP port 25 , SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP port 465).  Security type and internet connection settings also, but this didn't solve the problem not solved.

In CentOS with the same configuration like port, security type, incoming and outgoing mail settings and internet connection, everything works fine, so I think the cause must be specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: Any particular SMTP error, or just general "SMTP Error"?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: The error is " sending of the mail failed. The message could not be sent because of the connection to outgoing server (SMTP). mail.xxxx.com timed out. try again."   This error happens only in Ubuntu O/S Thunderbird mail client. In CentOS, Thunderbird is working fine without any error.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan did you ever find a solution?  I am experiencing the same error/problem.  I tried setting the "Place a copy in Sent folder on..." to the local folder (instead of the SMTP server's sent folder), just in case the timeout is caused by the copying the e-mail to the server.  That did not solve the issue.